# trying to pass values from php to jquery for my registration form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to pass values from php back to my jquery so the error message can be dynamically changed. any help would be mostly appreciated. the below code shows what i have tried so far.

jquery page

```
function validate(fname) {
    $.post('php/registration.php', {
        fname: fname
    }, function (data) {
        $('#fname_feedback').text(data.fname);

    });
}

$('#fname').focusin(function () {
    if ($('#fname').val() === '') {
        $('#fname_feedback').text('requried field');
    } else {
        validate($('#fname').val());
    }
}).blur(function () {
    $('#fname_feedback').text('');
    validate($('#fname').val());
}).keyup(function () {
    validate($('#fname').val());
});
```

php page

```
<?php
    require '../init.php';
    $data = array("fname" => '$fname');
    if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    if (strlen($fname) < 5) {
        $fname = 'fname must be greater than five letters long';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

registration form

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="fname" size ="25" placeholder="firstname" />
<span id="fname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="lname" size ="25" placeholder="lastname" />
<span id="lname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="username" size ="25" placeholder="username"/>
<span id="username_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="email" size ="25" placeholder="email"/>
<span id="email_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="email2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm email"/>
<span id="email2_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="password" size ="25" placeholder="password"/>
<span id="password_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="password2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm password"/>
<span id="password2_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="submit" id="reg" value="sign up">



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your <form></form> also

Comment: iv added my registration form

Comment: but, no <form> tag present.

Comment: yeah because i am posting the data using jquery to php

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="registration.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return CheckValidation()">
    <input type="text" id="fname" size ="25" placeholder="firstname"  onkeyup="FirstName()"/>
    <span id="fname_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" size ="25" placeholder="lastname" />
    <span id="lname_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="username" size ="25" placeholder="username"/>
    <span id="username_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="email" size ="25" placeholder="email"/>
    <span id="email_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="email2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm email"/>
    <span id="email2_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="password" size ="25" placeholder="password"/>
    <span id="password_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="password2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm password"/>
    <span id="password2_feedback"></span></br></br>
    <input type="submit" id="reg" value="sign up">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
//Create One JS File Here. Keep All Those Validation Here
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FormJValidation.js"></script>
```

**FormJValidation.js**

```
$(function FirstName() {
      $("#fname").blur(function ()
      {
        var FName=$('#fname').val();
        if(strlen(FName) < 5)
          $('#fname_feedback').text('fname must be greater than five letters long');
      });
    });
    function CheckValidation()
    {
        var FName=$('#fname').val();
        var LName=$('#lname').val();
        var UserName=$('#username').val();
        var Email=$('#email').val();
        var ConfirmEmail=$('#email2').val();
        var Password=$('#password').val();
        var ConfirmPassword=$('#password2').val();
        if(FName=="")
        {
            $('#fname_feedback').text('requried field');
            return ErrorMessage;
        }
        if(strlen(FName) < 5)
        {
            $('#fname_feedback').text('fname must be greater than five letters long');
            return false;
        }
        if(LName=="")
        {
            $('#lname_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(UserName=="")
        {
            $('#username_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(Email=="")
        {
            $('#email_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(ConfirmEmail=="")
        {
            $('#email2_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(Password=="")
        {
            $('#password_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(ConfirmPassword=="")
        {
            $('#password2_feedback').text('requried field');
            return false;
        }
        if(ConfirmPassword!=Password)
        {
            $('#password2_feedback').text('Password & Confirm Password Not Matched');
            return false;
        }
    }
```